# Reading Dynamic Content From JavaScript

Tags: javascript

We have a viewer written in a combination of HTML and JavaScript that displays our own personal content.  A need has come up to display a webpage from another domain inside our viewer.  Is there any way to do this in a combination of JavaScript and HTML?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using an iframe?

Answer (score 3):

Displaying is easy, just use [frames](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html) like

```
<iframe src="http://other-domain.example.com/some/page" />
```

(created either statically or dynamically). Only reading the cross-domain content of the frame will not be allowed due to the [same-origin-policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), you would need to use a proxy on your own domain for that.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this "proxy" concept for me?  I would like to display the contents of a survey from Survey Monkey, so the URL would look something like:  http://www.surveymonkey.com?survey=234ju

Comment: If you only want to display the page from surveymonkey.com, you don't need a proxy.

Comment: On this survey monkey page there will be questions that the user fills out and hits the submit to transmit the information.  Will I need a proxy for this or will ordinary JavaScript work?

Comment: No, you can't access the submitted values from outside of the iframe. You will need to server the survey from your own domain - you might be able to use an API from surveyymonkey.com to build one

Comment: Would it be possible to save the URL for this particular survey, say:   surveymonkey.com?survey=234ju  to a web page on the current domain and then call that?  Not sure if this will work when the user hits the submit button on this particular form?

Comment: No, saving a static page is not enough for a formular. The point of the Proxy is only that the browser does not send the authentification credentials for surveymonkey.com to you

Answer (score 1):

Iframes ?
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

but content will not be accesible by javascript
however you can fetch de page in serverside code (php for example), get the data you need and then use html/javascript to display it